# How do you append to a PDO resultset array or Json_encoded string?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to add a bit more information to a json object before sending it back to my app.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE repo=?";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($repo));  
$res = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$res['isnew']="1"; //this part isn't working
echo '{"items":'. json_encode($res) .'}';
```

The PDO query returns a result set like this when I echo($res)

```
 Array{"items":[{"uid":"10","repo":"bnef"}]}
```

then it gets encoded back to jquery- echo '{"items":'. json_encode($res) .'}'; 
giving me

```
{"items":[{"uid":"10","repo":"bnef}]}
```

I'd like to add "isnew":"1" to that but when I try
$res['isnew']="1"; or array_merge I end up with

```
{"items":{"0":{"uid":"10","repo":"bnef"},"isnew":"1"}}
```

which doesn't work. I need

```
{"items":[{"uid":"10","repo":"bnef, "isnew":"1"}]}
```

Am I misguide in try to do this?

Comment: You need to work on the array, not the json. Show your actual PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread your question and got confused on the code... you shoudl incat be dealign with an array initially try the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE repo=?";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($repo));

$items = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// you actually wnt isnew as a property of each row 
// so you need to loop over the results
foreach($items as $key => $item){
   $item->isnew = 1;
}

echo json_encode(array(
  'items' => $items
));
```

---

```
$res = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$res['isnew']="1"; //this part isn't working
```

Its not working because you used `FETCH_OBJ` instead of `FETCH_ASSOC` so youre wokring with an `StdObject` instance not an array. In that case you need to use `->` to assign:

```
$res = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$res->isnew = "1";
```

Alternatively you could fetch as an associative array:

```
$res = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$res['isnew']="1"; //this will work now
```

Additionalyl i wouldnt try to manipulate the JSON serialized string. I would doo all modifications natively:

```
$items = array(
  'items' => $res
);

echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: I may have some other problem but FETCH_ASSOC gave me the same result {"items":{"0":{"uid":"10","repo":"bnef"},"isnew":"1"}}

Comment: I agree, checking the json output just let me know I had a problem.

Comment: Also fetch_All is giving me all the rows. In this case it is returning only one. To get inside that I needed to get inside row 0:  $res0 = $res[0]; Then I can add to that:  $res0['isnew']="1" and put that back in row 0 $newres[0]=$res0. Now json_encode($newres) gets me what I want. Thanks