# PHP mySQL get all the headers of the table and values

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have connected to a table of the database and found a row by using the unique column header 'name';

I want a function now that allows me to get the value for each of the headers. Then an echo for each eg. `$post->header1; $post->header2; post->header3;`

etc...

How do we do this

EDIT

THIS returns one field. It seams overly expensive to do this for each one. Can we not grab them all in an array or something like that... and how?

```
function get($table,$name,$field){
    $the_page = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = '$name'"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($the_page)) { return $row[$field]; }
};
```

Comment: So far I', doing an individual mySQL query for each. This seams overly expensive

Comment: this method will always return only the first $field in the first record of the resultset

Comment: PDO might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949254/how-do-you-append-to-a-pdo-resultset-array-or-json-encoded-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the mySQL array as a variable and then return the result inside a variable with the table name as the column in question.

```
$find = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = '$post'"); 
    $find = mysql_fetch_array($find);

<?php echo $find['title'];?>
```